# Terminal commands not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: execute-command

I tried:

```
startx
```

and it didn't work saying:

`startx is not recognized as an internal or external command`

And tried:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

But I get:

`sudo is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Then I tried: removing `sudo` and again showed:

`apt-get is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Answer (score 5):

The phrase

> ... is not recognized as an internal or external command

Is specific to Windows. That is to say, you're at a Windows command prompt.

Use Ubuntu. You'll find your commands work slightly better there.